# Make Bash script with "chattr" work under OS X

Tags: macos, bash

Can anyone help me adapt this script to Mac OS X?

```
USR=$(logname)
f=`find /home/$USR/documents -name "*.doc" -o -name "*.xsl" -o -name "*.pdf"`
for file in $f
do
   chattr +i $f
done
```

My goal is to find files with this extension and can not be deleted afterwards, which is achieved by chattr +i in linux

Comment: It would help if you explain what you are trying to do (I can see what your script is doing, I want to know what you expect it to do).

Comment: Why do you store the output of `find` in `$f` and then iterate over that when you could simply do everything from `find` itself with the `-exec` option? Your script will fail for any file that even has a space in its name. You should never use command substitution to iterate over something that outputs filenames. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions

Comment: If you want to achieve the same effect as "locking" a file in its *Get Info* dialog, that's `chflags uchg $f`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be happy to comment on your script if you explain what you want it to do. As far as I know, the `chattr` command is specific to linux. From its man page:

> NAME
>       chattr - change file attributes **on a Linux file system**

If all you want is to make files returned by that find command read-only, try this:

```
find $HOME/documents -name "*.doc" -o -name "*.xsl" -o -name "*.pdf" -exec chmod 444 {} \;
```

**Update:** If Daniel Beck's suggestion is what you need, you can incorporate it into the find command:

```
find $HOME/documents -name "*.doc" -o -name "*.xsl" -o -name "*.pdf" -exec chflags uchg {} \;
```

I still don't understand why you need a script. The `USR=$(logname)` is useless since all you want is the current user's home directory and that is already in $HOME.

Comment: My goal is to find  files with this extension and can not be deleted afterwards, which is achieved by chattr +i in linux=

Comment: In that case, my suggestion should also work, it makes the files read-only.

Comment: To execut this script yor need sudo(chattr is needet) , then $home is root home!